# Thread 1: "Unsupported type: UITextField for value <UITextField: 0x7fdaa2f20380; frame = (134 168; 97 34); text = 'email';

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments

My xcode error - Thread 1: "Unsupported type: UITextField for value <UITextField: 0x7fdaa2f20380; frame = (134 168; 97 34); text = 'email'; .....

Here is my Viewcontroller:-

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import Stripe
import FirebaseFunctions
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
    var paymentContext = STPPaymentContext()

    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirm: UITextField!
    
    @IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if password.text != passwordConfirm.text {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!) {
                (user, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupToHome", sender: self)

                }
                else {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
        Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeUser").call(["email": email]) {
            (result, error) in

            if let error = error {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            self.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot  of my error:-
[image]

Earlier the everything was working fine but out of nowhere it started showing this error. what went wrong ?

Comment: try this 

`Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeUser").call(["email": email.text ?? ""])`

Comment: yes now it works, but still not creating stripe customer. by the way, what was wrong in my code

Comment: "call(["email": email.text ?? ""]" It was expecting you to give the `String` parameter, not a `UITextField`. The string value could come from any place, so give the String value directly. "but still not creating stripe customer" You need to debug that part, explain what's wrong, what's happening, etc? Maybe another question. What's the value of `result` in that case?

Comment: Debugger failed, so print the value…

Comment: @Larme - "po result" says 
error: <EXPR>:8:1: error: generic parameter 'Success' could not be inferred
Result
^

error: <EXPR>:8:1: error: generic parameter 'Failure' could not be inferred
Result
^

<EXPR>:8:1: note: explicitly specify the generic arguments to fix this issue
Result
^
      <Any, <#Failure: Error#>>

Comment: I meant `print(result)`. Or, if you would handle correctly the `result`: `switch result { case success(let s): print(s); case failure(let f): print(s) }` depending on how `result` is define in your method.

Comment: @Larme print(result) is nil

Comment: And `debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)` doesn't print? What's the doc saying about the possible values? What could mean that `result` is `nil`?

Comment: @Larme  po debugPrint  says- po function 'debugPrint' with unknown type must be given a function type
debugPrint

Comment: I meant the line in your code, inside the `if let error = error {`.

Comment: @Larme -It says "unauthenticated"

Comment: So, you didn't authenticate: so it needs one, where do you do it? Does `Functions.functions().httpsCallable()` needs to be done AFTER `Auth.auth().createUse()`?

Comment: That didn;'t help. Please see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70647665/debugprint-says-uauthenticated