# debugPrint says "UAUTHENTICATED"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, stripe-payments

I am trying to link firebasse with stripe to my ios app.

The debugPrint in my code in the console says "UNAUTHENTICATED

This is my Viewontroller-

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import Stripe
import FirebaseFunctions
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
    var paymentContext = STPPaymentContext()
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirm: UITextField!
    @IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if password.text != passwordConfirm.text {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else{
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){
                (user, error) in if error == nil {
                }
                else{
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
        Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeUser").call(["email": email.text ?? ""]) {
            (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            self.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```

The debugPrint line in my code above "UNAUTHENTICATED" in the console as shown beolow:-

[image]

As you can see the customer is created in the FirebaseAuth as shown below:-

[image]

**Also, the stripe customer is not created**

How to sort it-out?

After edit suggested by Frank van Puffelen, viewcontroller code -

```
import UIKit
 import FirebaseFirestore
 import FirebaseAuth
import Stripe
import FirebaseFunctions

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
var paymentContext = STPPaymentContext()

@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirm: UITextField!
@IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if password.text != passwordConfirm.text {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){ [self]
            (user, error) in if error == nil {
                // 
                Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeUser").call(["email": self.email.text ?? ""]) {
                    (result, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    self.dismiss(animated: true)
                }
            }
            else{
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
       }
         }
 }
```

That didnt help.

Comment: Is it just me or you are NOT calling the createStropeUser function from the Auth completion?

Comment: Are you sending the correct headers/data for the Stripe API call?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur i am sorry, i didn't follow you

Comment: @AbhinavMathur the jeys are properly placed, the functions are deployed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code that needs to run *after* the user was created needs to be inside the completion handler for `createUser(withEmail:, password:)`. So move the call `httpsCallable("createStripeUser")` into that block:

```
@IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if password.text != passwordConfirm.text {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){
            (user, error) in if error == nil {
                // 
                Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeUser").call(["email": email.text ?? ""]) {
                    (result, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    self.dismiss(animated: true)
                }
            }
            else{
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```