# callable function returns error - Domain=com.firebase.functions Code=16 "UNAUTHENTICATED" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=UNAUTHENTICATED}

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments

```
 import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import Stripe
import FirebaseFunctions

 class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
  var paymentContext = STPPaymentContext()
 let  functions = Functions.functions()
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirm: UITextField!
@IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if password.text != passwordConfirm.text {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){ [self]
            (user, error) in if error == nil {
                // 
                functions.httpsCallable("createStripeUser").call(["email": self.email.text ?? ""]) {
                    (result, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("yed")
                        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    self.dismiss(animated: true)
                }
            }
            else{
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I do po error in the line for breakpoint  for line "debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)", it shows error - callable function returns error - Domain=com.firebase.functions Code=16 "UNAUTHENTICATED" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=UNAUTHENTICATED}

Here is my index.js code -

```
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');
  const admin = require('firebase-admin')
  const stripe = require('stripe') ('sk_test_51HmAsMFzRM1fSBZ2CkBBjW5a3sEpxEQLGT7OkGxa8BZMMfgzT1Jeqs7dq63AlPRLIJmzHFC0HHAmKHDazcpriuh9001IWIVmw1');

   admin.initializeApp()

   const db = admin.firestore()
   const storage = admin.storage().bucket()
  const auth = admin.auth()

  exports.createStripeUser = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {

  const email = data.email
  const uid = context.auth.uid

   if (uid === null) {
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Illegal access attempt')
 }

   return stripe.customers.create({
   email: email,
   })
.then(customer => {
return customer["id"]
})
     .then( customerId => {
    admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).set(
  {
   stripeId: customerId,
   email: email,
   id: uid
    }
       )
  })
   .catch( err => {
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create Stripe  customer')
})
})

    exports.createEphemeralKey = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

   const customerId = data.customer_id;
  const stripeVersion = data.stripe_version;
  const uid = context.auth.uid;

   if (uid === null) {
  console.log('Illegal access attempt due to unauthenticated attempt.')
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Illegal access attempt');
  }

  return stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
   { customer: customerId },
 { stripe_version: stripeVersion }
  ).then((key) => {
 return key
   }).catch( (err) => {
  functions.logger.log('Error creating ephemeral key', err)
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create ephemeral key: ' + err)
 })
 })

   exports.createPaymentIntent = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {

  const total = data.total
  const idempotency = data.idempotency
 const customer = context.auth.uid

  const uid = context.auth.uid;

 if (uid === null) {
 console.log('Illegal access attempt due to unauthenticated attempt.')
 throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Illegal access attempt');
  }

 return stripe.paymentIntents.create(
 {
    amount: total,
     currency: 'usd',
   customer: customer,
   payment_method_types: ['card', 'ach_debit']
 },
 {
 idempotencyKey: idempotency
    }
    ).then( intent => {
     return intent.client_secret
   }).catch( err => {
     functions.logger.log('Unable to create Stripe Payment Intent.')
  return null
   })
   })


    exports.fetchBankSources = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

     const customerId = data.customer_id

    const bankAccounts = await stripe.customers.listSources(
     customerId,
     { object: 'bank_account'}
    )

return { banks: bankAccounts.data }
    })

    exports.deleteSource = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

   const customerId = data.customer_id
    const source = data.source

    return stripe.customers.deleteSource(customerId, source)
  .then(res => {
   return {
    status: 200
    }
   })
  .catch(err => {
  functions.logger.log(err)
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to delete bank source: ' + err)
  })
})

   // PLAID
    const plaid = require('plaid');

   exports.createPlaidLinkToken = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

   const customerId = context.auth.uid
   const env = functions.config().app.env

   let plaidEnv = plaid.environments.sandbox

  if (env === 'production') {
  plaidEnv = plaid.environments.development
     } else {
    plaidEnv = plaid.environments.sandbox
}

  const plaidClient = new plaid.Client({
 clientID: functions.config().plaid.client_id,
    secret: functions.config().plaid.secret,
 env: plaidEnv,
options: {
  version: '2019-05-29'
   }
   })

      return plaidClient.createLinkToken({
     user: {
    client_user_id: customerId
    },
    client_name: 'Bon Voyage',
   products: ['auth'],
 country_codes: ['US'],
 language: 'en',
 redirect_uri: 'https://bon-voyage.jonnybcodes.com'
   })
     .then((apiResponse) => {
   const linkToken = apiResponse.link_token
return linkToken
  })
  .catch((err) => {
   functions.logger.log(err)
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create plaid link token: '  + err)
  })
  })

   exports.createPlaidBankAccount = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  const token = data.publicToken
 const custId = data.stripeId
 const bankAccountId = data.accountId

const env = functions.config().app.env

 let plaidEnv = plaid.environments.sandbox

  if (env === 'production') {
 plaidEnv = plaid.environments.development
  } else {
   plaidEnv = plaid.environments.sandbox
   }

  const plaidClient = new plaid.Client({
 clientID: functions.config().plaid.client_id,
  secret: functions.config().plaid.secret,
   env: plaidEnv,
  options: {
version: '2019-05-29'
   }
    })

     return plaidClient.exchangePublicToken(token)
  .then(res => {

    const accessToken = res.access_token
   return plaidClient.createStripeToken(accessToken, bankAccountId)

  })
 .then(resp => {

   const bankAccountToken = resp.stripe_bank_account_token
    return stripe.customers.createSource(custId, {
      source: bankAccountToken
    }).then(bank => {
     return bank
   })

  })
 .catch((err) => {
   functions.logger.log(err)
   throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create plaid link token: ' + err)
     })
    })
```

The functions deployed in the simulator:-

[image]

I am  trying to create a stripe customer desparately but unsuccessful. plz help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [debugPrint says "UAUTHENTICATED"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70647665/debugprint-says-uauthenticated)

Comment: yes it does now